# Strange behaivure with Laravel 6 Arguments in Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a strange behaivure found while creating a Laravel 6 controller.

I have two routes called

```
Route::resource('role', 'RoleController')->middleware('verified');
Route::resource('category', 'MainCategoryController')->middleware('verified');
```

Both work fine.
In both controllers I have an edit method

RoleController

```
public function edit(Role $role)
    {
        $permissions = Permission::get();
        $users = User::get();
        return view('roles.edit', compact('role', 'permissions', 'users'));
    }
```

MainCategoryController

```
public function edit($mainCategory)
    {
        $mainCategory = MainCategory::findOrFail($mainCategory);
        // dd($mainCategory);
        return view('categories.edit', compact('mainCategory'));
    }
```

My problem is, if I use in in MainCategoryController.edit as argument **MainCategory $mainCategroy** it does not give me the data of the model instead it is looking like this. In normal cases if it cant find the model is routes to 404.

```
App\MainCategory {#471 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: array:1 [▶]
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #forceDeleting: false
}
```

If I ask for the model data as in the function above everything works fine. In the RoleController.edit it works fine and I get the data I asked for.

I have no idea why it is working in Role and not in MainCategory.

Maybe someone has an idea what I did wrong here, because I can't figure out my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable name must match the name of the parameter in the route. If you do a `php artisan route:list`, you are going to see something along these lines:

```
| GET|HEAD  | category/{category}/edit | category.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\MainCategoryController@edit    | web        |
```

Which means your controller needs to have the signature like this:

```php
public function edit(MainCategory $category)
{
   dd($category);
}
```

If your variable name does not match, like in your case, it will create a new instance because of [dependency injection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers):

```php
public function edit(MainCategory $mainCategory)
{
    dd($mainCategory); // New instance of App\MainCategory
}
```

You can read more about implicit binding: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: Take a while to understand what you mean but in the end It helped to solved my Problem. Thank you very much.